# Make span fill a tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap mark up with `a` tags containing `span` elements with glyphicon classes. However, I can't set the `span` glyphicon to stretch to the full extent of the width available by the `a` tag. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<a class='app-nav--links' href='#'>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
```

SCSS:

```
.app-nav {
    .app-nav--links {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 60px;
      & span {
        width: 100%;
        display:inline-block;
      }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried declaring `display: block` for the `span` elements in question?

Comment: Yes, doesn't work...

Comment: The code you have shown works (once the SCSS is turned into CSS), so it must be something else that is causing the issue. What exactly is happening? Can you create a working snippet to illustrate the issue? [How to create a runnable code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: You can see a few examples here: https://jsfiddle.net/k4a71tnt/8/ demonstrating how these style rules apply as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved it by adding `font-size` to the `span` tag. Here's the code:

```
.app-nav {
    .app-nav--links {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 60px;

      span {
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 50px;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually made the span fill the tag. If you want to increase the size of glyphicon you should increase its `font-size`.